# Elegantly removing the part of a string after the last occurrence of a character

Tags: c++, string

Suppose I want to remove everything after the last '*' (for example) in a string. Knowing that I can take the following for granted for that string:

1. It will ALWAYS contain a '*'
2. It MAY contain more than one '*'
3. It will NEVER start or end with a '*'

What is the cleanest and/or shortest way to remove everything past the last '*', plus itself, with only basic libraries?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Given your assumptions:

```
s.erase(s.rfind('*'));
```

Without the assumption that it contains at least one `*`:

```
auto pos = s.rfind('*');
if (pos != std::string::npos) {
    s.erase(pos);
}
```

Comment: Say. What is the difference between .rfind() and .find_last_of()?

Comment: Although I am dangerously close to spamming, I found the answer to that last question: s.rfind("abc") will find the last occurrence of the string "abc", and s.find_last_of("abc") will find the last occurrence of 'a', 'b' or 'c'.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC: Yes that's right. But here you're just looking for a single character, so both are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Since [`rfind`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/rfind/) returns the index of the target char or string, we can also use [`resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize) to cut the unwanted part of the input string.

```cpp
s.resize(s.rfind('*'));
```

Comment: ... is resize better than erase?

Comment: According to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918394/difference-between-stdstringresize-and-stdstringerase-when-shortening-st), `resize` does a few more boundary checks and has a stronger exception safety, which also means it could be slightly slower than `erase`. I am not sure how to define "better" here, but I feel like `erase` is more often used together with `remove` to fit the erase-remove idiom in C++.