# Difference between std::string::resize and std::string::erase when shortening string

Tags: c++, c++11

When shortening a `std::string` there are basically two possibilities: `string.resize(length)` or `string.erase(length)`.

Given that we know a string will become smaller, what are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 2):

1. `resize` must check if `length > current` or `length < current` - it's behavior depends on result of сomparison. `erase` always reduce length of string
2. There is difference in exception safety:

   - `resize`: Strong guarantee: if an exception is thrown, there are no changes in the string. ( from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) )
   - `erase`: C++98 - equal to `resize`; C++14 - there is no-throw version of function ( from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/erase/) )